# Redondear a 5 cifras decimales para cualquier idioma en que se ponga el telefono

Tags: android-studio, idioma

Estoy usando la clase Decimal format en el codigo que tengo abajo, pero no logro conseguir que al cambiar de idioma en mi telefono esta funcione siempre (cuando digo que no funciona me refiero a que no setea el valor numerico en el textview que necesito, pero el problema no es ese ya que como lo digo , en algunos idiomas si setea el texto normal . Y el problema no es de traducción porque si no utilizo dicha formateo o redondeo, el código funciona perfectamente para todos los idiomas

Aqui parte de mi codigo donde esta el problema:

```
public void conversor(Double a, Double a1, Double a2,Double a3,Double a4,Double a5,Double a6,Double a7,Double a8,Double a9,Double a10,Double a11){

        m.setText("  " + a+ " m");
        cm.setText("  " + a1 + " cm");
        km.setText("  " + a2 + " km");
        dc.setText("  "+a3+" dm");
        mm.setText("  "+a4+" mm");
        mc.setText("  "+a5+" mc");
        nm.setText("  "+a6+" nm");
        pies.setText("  "+a7+ " ft");
        pulgadas.setText("  "+a8+" inch");
        millas.setText("  "+a9+" "+getResources (). getString(R.string.millas));
        yardas.setText("  "+a10+" yd");
        leguas.setText("  "+a11+" "+getResources (). getString(R.string.leguas));
    } 


    textoizqu=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.textoizq);
     try {
               textoizqu.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
                { @Override public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
                { if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)
                {  try {a = Double.parseDouble(textoizqu.getText().toString());
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,#####");
                  conversor(Double.parseDouble(df.format(a)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*100)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a/1000)),               Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*10)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*1000)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*1000000)),                    Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*1000000000)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*3.28084)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*39.3701)),                   Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*0.000621371)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*1.09361)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a* 0.00020712)));
                    }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    a=0.0;

                }
                } return false; } });
                a = Double.parseDouble(textoizqu.getText().toString());

                conversor(Double.parseDouble(df.format(a)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*100)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a/1000)),
                        Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*10)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*1000)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*1000000)),
                        Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*1000000000)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*3.28084)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*39.3701)),
                        Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*0.000621371)),
                        Double.parseDouble(df.format(a*1.09361)),Double.parseDouble(df.format(a* 0.00020712)));
            } catch (Exception e) {

               a=0.0;

            }
```

Comment: Debes agregar mas información. Como cual es el formato que te esta dando y cual es el que quieres. Tambien debes agregar la clase con los métodos y variables relevantes; por ejemplo, de que tipo es la variable `a`. Otra cosa es, por qué primero formateas los valores y después los conviertes a `Double`, no debería ser al revés?

Comment: Amigo en el metodo conversor se muestra muy claramente que la a es de tipo Double, y sensillamente quiero el formato que ves ahi, pero no me arroja absolutamente nada, es decir, al introducir el valor numérico en el Edit text se supone que debe setear el texto en el text view correspondiente como sucede en algunos idiomas, pero no me aparece nada en el textview queda vacio, y eso sucede en otros varios idiomas

Comment: Me refiero a esta a: conversor(Double.parseDouble(df.format(**a**)). Y esa no es la forma de responderle a alguien que quiere ayudarte. *al introducir el valor numérico en el Edit text se supone*, entonces el problema no parece ser el formateo. Puedes agregar el código del EditText y del TextView.

Comment: Disculpa, no quice que sonara de esa manera, pero acabo de ponerlo al revés como me dijiste y no me acepta, me dice que debe ser un Double, por eso primero hago el formato y luego aplico el cambio a Double. Por cierto ya edite mi pregunta para ver si la entiendes mejor

Comment: El problema no es en el Edit text porque por ejemplo si mi telefono esta en el idioma espalo( estados unidos) funciona normal, de hecho en varios idiomas, pero cuando escojo por ejemplo el idioma español( españa) en mi telefono, al introducir el valor en el edittext no arroja nada en el textview. De hecho si le quito ese formato funciona normal en todos los idiomas